# Graph partitioning with graphx/spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I want to make a graph partitioning using graphx/spark . Before implementing it myself and after some serching I wanted to ask you whether there is already a solution.

Is there an implementation for Graphx/Spark that can be used to divide a graph's vertices into a specified number of subsets such that:

- the number of vertices per subset is more or less equal
- the number of edges between the subsets is minimized
- all vertices inside of subset are connected to each other using edges that belong to the subset (directly or via several egdes)

?

Inside of the PartitionStrategy.scala there are several strategies: EdgePartition2D, EdgePartition1D, RandomVertexCut, CanonicalRandomVertexCut. None of them seem to be good for the problem.

Comment: Requirement 1 and 2 are roughly handled by the heuristics in the bundled strategies. I can't see how the third can be done easily directly as a strategy, i.e. without spending time actually finding the subsets first. If you do that, you could create a strategy to partition by attribute (i.e. through a vertexId lookup table).

Answer (score -2):

Finally I could not find out of box solution and just made a simple implementation with Pregel.

Comment: This is not an answer. Can you describe your solution ?